# Is there a way to set alert for multiple ENUM metrics with similar name

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to handle multiple (around 500) metrics with similar names like:

```
INSTANCE03{INSTANCE03="Dead"} == 1
INSTANCE05{INSTANCE05="Dead"} == 1
INSTANCE07{INSTANCE07="Dead"} == 1
```

Each of them is specified as an Enum which shows status like this:

```
INSTANCE03{INSTANCE03="Dead"} == 1
INSTANCE03{INSTANCE03="Alive"} == 0
```

Is there a way to make an alert for switching the status from Alive to Dead for all those metrics in some short way e. g. using regex for __name__ value?

Alerting works if I specify one metric instance per line but it's not a clean way for so many metrics.

Below my alert_rules.yml

```
groups:
 - name: example
   rules:
   - alert: InstanceDown
     expr: INSTANCE03{INSTANCE03="Dead",instance="127.0.0.1:8888",job="prometheus"} == 1
     for: 15s
     annotations:
       summary: "Instance is down."
       description: "Instance down for 15 seconds. Please check mentioned instance."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `labelmap` action in `metric_relabel_configs` to fix up these label and metric names.

As Alin says though, fixing the source of the metrics is best. A gauge with a 0/1 per instance would be simplest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no way in Prometheus to deal with arbitrary labels (i.e. your `INSTANCE03="Dead"` labels), apart from defining a [`label_join()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_join) or [`<relabel_config>`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) where you enumerate all possible label names and replace them with a fixed label (such as `state`).

It is going to be a lot easier to go back to whatever is exporting those metrics and fixing it there, before they ever make it into Prometheus.